# Heat map in ggplot - no color variation

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I would like to plot simple heatmap using `ggplot`

```
library(ggplot2)

my_df <- data.frame(var_1 = sample(c('a','b', 'c'), 1000, replace = TRUE),
                    var_2 = sample(c('foo', 'bar', 'foo_bar'), 1000, replace = TRUE),
                    var_3 = sample(c(1,0), 1000, replace = TRUE))

ggplot(data = my_df, aes(x = var_1, y = var_2, fill = var_3)) +
  geom_tile()
```

Here is what I get:
[image: Heat map]

I cannot understand where there is no color variation. I changed number of rows in `sample` function, but always received only two colors in heat map. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `geom_tile` with a layer that computes the statistical transformation you desire:

```
ggplot(data = my_df, aes(x = var_1, y = var_2)) + 
  stat_summary_2d(fun = "mean", geom = "tile", 
                  aes(z = var_3, fill = ..value..))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

that's because the only values you are choosing to input are either 0 or 1 from your vector in your `var_3 = sample(c(1,0), 1000, replace = TRUE)`. If instead you want to choose values between 0 and 1, use this code instead:

`var_3 = sample(0:10, 1000, replace = TRUE)/10`

Comment: Thank you, how do I make `fill` reflect proportion of 1 and 0. I know how to do it manually, I wonder if `ggplot` can do it automatically.

Comment: what do you mean? shouldn't it automatically happen when you set `fill = var_3`?

Answer (score 2):

To plot the proportion of 1 and 0 by factor, you will need to calculate the mean of `var_3` for each combination of `var_1` and `var_2`.  Here I show how to do that using `data.table`, although you could also use `dplyr.summarise` or  `aggregate` from base R.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(my_df)
ggplot(data = my_df[, var_3 := mean(var_3), by = .(var_1,var_2)], 
       aes(x = var_1, y = var_2, fill = var_3)) +
  geom_tile()
```